# Efficiently filtering the oldest record in a dataframe according to each id

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe with the following details:

[image]

For each `q_id` there might be multiple `ph_id` with different `ph_date`.

I want to make a new dataframe out of it, in a way that for each `q_id` there is just one `ph_id` and that is the oldest (with minimum date).

I tried the following code but I think it is computationally slow:

```
def oldest_ph(q_id):
    return a.loc[a.ph_date == a[a['q_id'] == q_id].ph_date.min(), 'ph_date']

b['oldest_date'] = a['q_id'].apply(lambda x: a(x))
```

Is there any better way for this point?

Comment: `df.sort_values('date').drop_duplicates('q_id')`.

Comment: @QuangHoang `drop_duplicates` always keeps the first row and drop other duplicates?

Comment: Yes, or do you want to keep all the rows but replace just `q_id`?

Comment: @QuangHoang I want to drop them.

Comment: Now I'm confused. Anyway, the first comment drops all duplicates but the first rows. My answer extents to when you want to replace **all original** `ph_id` with those corresponding oldest ones.

Comment: @QuangHoang No I don't want to replace them, just want to keep the oldest record. So, your comment actually did the trick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, let try extracting the oldest `ph_id` for each `q_id`, then you can use map:

```
s = df.sort_values('date').drop_duplicates('q_id').set_index('q_id')
df['ph_id'] = df['q_id'].map(s['ph_id'])
```